# How normal are remote connection faults and what do they mean?

Tags: connection, isp, internet

**Quick background:** I have been having a lot of connection issues with my home network. I finally got my ISP to understand and after them checking some of the problems outside of my home I've gone from 5 timeouts an hour to at most 1. Some of these timeouts were causing my connection to drop 100% long enough for any live connection to fully disconnect.

**Explanation:** Today I was monitoring my connection (via pings to my first hop) and my connection dropped for every computer on the network at the same exact time for about 10 seconds. While every service running on our PCs and pings to Google stopped in their tracks, pings to my first hop continued without interruption.

**The Question:** Being that I've had connection problems, I have continued to monitor the connection to see if the problem was indeed fixed. Now, I wonder, how normal is the above situation? Should I accept this, or should I report this? Also, what is the most likely cause of such a problem?

Comment: This would be more well-answered over on Superuser. It'll get migrated over there shortly.

Comment: I didn't post it there due to it saying "home networking" only, and I don't consider this home networking, since it's on the remote end. :\

Comment: @Serodis [***Anything*** in a home setting is off-topic for Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions) (we have a generally accepted exception for VPNs and the like where local configuration and ISP issues have been ruled out, but you don't fit in that category). Your problem is either internal to your network, or between you and your ISP (it sounds like the latter to me).  If the outages are frequent enough to be a problem for normal use you should stay on your provider and insist it be fixed. If you would like this question moved to superuser let me know and I'll migrate it.